# Can you find me using a number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Can you find me?

December 2, 5:37 PM

A girl was alone at home, suddenly someone broke in and killed her.

The killer left a message with some numbers and words. "Hey, long time no see! I know you are a systematic person. Always know all things and everything should be in a certain pattern. You were always two steps ahead of everyone! But do not worry, I have a puzzle / riddle for you. I will confess to my murder only if you find me this week. If you can not, then I will run away and you will not find me again.

Solve this code then you will find me. Remember! You have to solve it by using logic.

Hint: You'll have 6 hours 46 minutes to solve this and do not be stupid. Solve this riddle and find me. 2 problems but only one riddle!

11331811325181863171825187131200101112511

It should not be difficult!

Comment: That is 4825 in base 8

Comment: @bleh: It can't be ba 8 since it contains the digit 8.

Comment: 6h46m after 5:37pm on December 2 is (depending on how you write your dates and times) xxxx-12-03 00:23 or 12:23 on 12/3 or something of the sort. That's a lot of "small" digits.

Comment: 4825 in base 8 is 2581...

Comment: Base 8 uses digits 0-7. Neither 4825 nor 2581 could be base 8 numbers.

Comment: can you provide more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11331811325181863171825187131200101112511

The process:

> The hint here is two steps ahead and two problems but one riddle i.e combine two or one numbers to form a number, add two and the result denotes a letter of english alphabet.

So, it comes to:

> 11 is valid so its 11 + 2  = 13 = m(in English). 33 is not valid, so take 3 + 2 = 5 = e and Go on. 11(m)3(e)3(e)18(t)

The answer (halfway):

> meet me at the station